# WSO2 Datamapper shwoing not found in postman

Tags: wso2, datamapper, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I am trying to use data mapper in wso2 and translating the json to xml but it doesn't showing any result instead it showing page not found in POSTMAN.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/TEST" name="TEST" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <datamapper config="gov:datamapper/NewConfig.dmc" inputSchema="gov:datamapper/NewConfig_inputSchema.json" inputType="JSON" outputSchema="gov:datamapper/NewConfig_outputSchema.json" outputType="XML"/>
            <property description="" name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Can you mention the URL which you are calling from POSTMAN, as i copied and pasted your code and tested and it looks fine, try using the below URL http://localhost:8280/TEST  (8280 will be the default port if you haven't changed the offset)

Comment: Do you see any error message in the console or wso2carbon.log file? In the configuration, you should use the 'messageType' property instead of the 'ContentType' property but it won't cause a page not found error anyway.